# Animating SVG Paths Using RaphaelJS and GSAP

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, gsap

I can progressively draw a basic path with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) but I'm having issue trying to incorporate [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)'s TweenLite/Max. I posted [this](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/8510-animating-svg-paths-within-a-timeline/#entry34076) on the [GSAP](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/) site but haven't had any replies so thought I'd add it here for better chances as well as it being here for others who may find this useful. I've used most of the examples in that GSAP post as reference so I won't go on about what I'm trying to accomplish etc. The jsfiddle here should be pretty straight forward. I'm hoping I'm just missing something entirely silly... I've been looking at soooo many different js canvas/svg drawing libraries in the last 5 days my head is spinning so maybe I'm just still stuck in another framework. :P Any thoughts on what I'm not doing right here?

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Jn3zg/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>
<div id="controls">
    <button id="native" type="button">Native</button>
    <button id="gsap" type="button">GSAP</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#canvas {
    float: left;
}
#controls {
    float: left;
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

JS:

```
var paper = new Raphael('canvas', 600, 600),
pathString = 'M 206.53939,490.41562 C 202.40433,496.12926 196.55503,503.89998 188.47724,507.72796 C 182.4113,509.44219 176.00252,509.44219 170.27943,507.72796 C 163.58247,503.34049 158.77116,498.7816 155.33124,491.47993 C 145.50143,484.36656 135.32876,477.42462 127.38461,468.08275 C 139.97609,474.03193 152.39614,485.80949 162.58769,487.98735 C 177.75253,488.6636 191.7174,488.48273 206.88224,485.90194 C 219.23818,478.003 224.22292,471.30402 231.77901,461.348 C 230.15521,447.82988 240.70247,441.85437 235.99305,442.90723 C 227.70605,451.04713 216.67627,452.33009 206.67504,453.78448 C 184.22542,456.11286 162.97575,457.92698 138.12621,455.96978 C 125.38421,459.40568 121.89906,457.52747 122.18524,447.93519 C 122.18524,441.43597 121.32812,431.85114 121.32812,425.35192 C 123.92781,429.25145 125.32753,438.29368 129.9843,440.13613 C 147.61317,441.63372 166.78485,440.73139 183.21376,439.82906 C 199.46923,438.82685 213.83905,438.85317 222.55189,436.13672 C 230.62969,434.34893 236.99326,430.16123 237.87127,426.48778 C 237.43799,420.85513 238.3761,414.19393 237.94282,408.56128 C 233.80776,415.79884 228.81558,418.92224 219.02355,419.98856 C 200.60911,421.93832 182.70893,423.54524 163.6088,423.78077 C 150.87222,424.37603 135.05003,427.19979 126.94189,422.65235 C 121.01308,426.21656 120.12812,418.82458 120.8854,413.48935 C 127.99475,403.507 114.87614,406.03856 118.3856,385.59939 C 120.552,389.71556 120.14705,400.51724 126.08477,403.0906 C 140.46403,405.3191 154.15761,404.80483 168.0226,404.80483 C 186.87032,405.02147 205.20378,405.06669 224.22292,403.74052 C 232.02942,403.28835 237.77883,400.0934 237.87127,397.24131 C 238.53808,391.39202 230.97655,386.39984 232.6719,379.69343 C 224.06837,386.4525 211.86497,387.55458 200.17582,388.14241 C 185.48949,389.17095 171.14599,389.34237 156.63108,388.14241 C 141.41359,387.94265 123.11048,386.02866 120.23548,380.34335 C 112.63618,372.5254 107.60823,362.99321 104.63736,351.7468 C 102.79692,340.87901 106.09918,331.55401 103.40162,321.20049 C 93.200631,299.54588 81.456827,279.60552 69.541601,258.80803 C 50.51903,224.05512 45.210335,192.2164 47.44427,153.52075 C 62.098848,108.2678 74.182075,84.957039 117.63579,59.932049 C 147.4944,44.673356 171.3532,44.328502 196.92622,47.58354 C 230.59935,52.118115 249.53007,66.252402 264.51805,80.729537 C 288.01853,102.63856 301.06217,128.83317 304.16326,154.17067 C 310.5417,177.42275 307.32043,198.61774 302.2135,219.81274 C 286.39874,251.44225 270.58399,283.07177 254.76923,314.70128 C 249.26279,324.27526 254.72743,353.04865 237.22135,378.39358 C 226.43454,383.7266 209.81934,388.88819 205.37519,383.59296 C 207.32496,378.61023 209.27472,373.62749 211.22449,368.64476 C 189.99372,369.29468 168.76295,369.94461 147.53218,370.59453 C 155.27457,370.23279 155.47432,370.04248 155.33124,365.39515 C 156.1978,349.36375 156.5501,336.93225 157.41666,320.90085 C 161.34251,313.78949 162.35417,310.10661 163.02298,305.90945 C 162.41627,300.09593 155.46689,298.73942 152.46025,287.61177 C 152.36238,280.15756 153.29304,279.38888 160.22354,276.73453 C 164.72777,278.91782 170.94624,279.38687 172.87912,275.05607 C 171.79592,255.34178 170.71271,235.6275 169.62951,215.91321 C 167.46311,200.09845 165.2967,184.2837 163.1303,168.46894 C 172.66248,168.68558 182.19466,168.90222 191.72684,169.11886 C 190.427,203.5647 187.07007,240.92474 185.77023,275.37058 C 189.80541,280.45119 193.8406,277.30346 199.24717,276.55567 C 204.10168,278.26247 205.3563,287.51189 203.35388,290.7615 C 202.80183,297.3417 196.24997,299.4649 194.32653,306.90222 C 206.39973,320.26439 200.98772,347.85472 203.80405,366.70244 M 161.70443,272.07413 C 148.01517,240.84549 134.3259,209.61686 120.63664,178.38822 C 132.07442,172.84968 139.59482,171.3636 151.84309,171.76866 C 154.45213,166.83049 154.49461,164.32378 159.12987,163.57314 C 166.79222,164.85848 169.99687,171.95235 178.87496,171.88687 C 188.87701,171.33578 192.80037,164.43584 199.83061,162.93918 C 205.16655,164.89993 203.47823,169.6974 206.78794,171.2529 C 217.88326,175.83905 227.76285,172.72552 236.29162,178.12216 C 223.73443,209.51513 211.17725,240.90809 198.62006,272.30106',
testLineDrawNative = function() {
    var triangle = paper.path(pathString).attr({
      stroke: '#000000'
    }),
    length = triangle.getTotalLength();
    $('path[fill*="none"]').animate({
      to: 1
    }, {
      duration: 5000,
      step: function(pos, fx) {
        var offset, subpath;
        offset = length*fx.pos;
        subpath = triangle.getSubpath(0, offset);
        paper.clear();
        paper.path(subpath).attr({
          stroke: '#000000'
        });
      }
    });
},
testLineDrawGSAP = function() {
    var triangle = paper.path(pathString).attr({
      stroke: '#000000'
    }),
    obj = {
      length: 0,
      pathLength: triangle.getTotalLength()
    },
    drawLine = function() {
      triangle.attr({
        strokeDashArray: [obj.length, obj.pathLength].join(' ')
      });
    };
    tween = TweenMax.to(triangle, 5, {
      raphael: {
        length: obj.pathLength,
        onUpdate: drawLine,
        ease: Linear.easeNone
      }
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        paper.clear();
        if($(this).prop('id') === 'native') {
            testLineDrawNative();
        } else {
            testLineDrawGSAP();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to [Carl](http://forums.greensock.com/topic/8510-animating-svg-paths-within-a-timeline/#entry34077).

New [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geekambassador/BG45h/1/h/)

New JS

```
var paper = new Raphael('canvas', 600, 600),
pathString = 'M 206.53939,490.41562 C 202.40433,496.12926 196.55503,503.89998 188.47724,507.72796 C 182.4113,509.44219 176.00252,509.44219 170.27943,507.72796 C 163.58247,503.34049 158.77116,498.7816 155.33124,491.47993 C 145.50143,484.36656 135.32876,477.42462 127.38461,468.08275 C 139.97609,474.03193 152.39614,485.80949 162.58769,487.98735 C 177.75253,488.6636 191.7174,488.48273 206.88224,485.90194 C 219.23818,478.003 224.22292,471.30402 231.77901,461.348 C 230.15521,447.82988 240.70247,441.85437 235.99305,442.90723 C 227.70605,451.04713 216.67627,452.33009 206.67504,453.78448 C 184.22542,456.11286 162.97575,457.92698 138.12621,455.96978 C 125.38421,459.40568 121.89906,457.52747 122.18524,447.93519 C 122.18524,441.43597 121.32812,431.85114 121.32812,425.35192 C 123.92781,429.25145 125.32753,438.29368 129.9843,440.13613 C 147.61317,441.63372 166.78485,440.73139 183.21376,439.82906 C 199.46923,438.82685 213.83905,438.85317 222.55189,436.13672 C 230.62969,434.34893 236.99326,430.16123 237.87127,426.48778 C 237.43799,420.85513 238.3761,414.19393 237.94282,408.56128 C 233.80776,415.79884 228.81558,418.92224 219.02355,419.98856 C 200.60911,421.93832 182.70893,423.54524 163.6088,423.78077 C 150.87222,424.37603 135.05003,427.19979 126.94189,422.65235 C 121.01308,426.21656 120.12812,418.82458 120.8854,413.48935 C 127.99475,403.507 114.87614,406.03856 118.3856,385.59939 C 120.552,389.71556 120.14705,400.51724 126.08477,403.0906 C 140.46403,405.3191 154.15761,404.80483 168.0226,404.80483 C 186.87032,405.02147 205.20378,405.06669 224.22292,403.74052 C 232.02942,403.28835 237.77883,400.0934 237.87127,397.24131 C 238.53808,391.39202 230.97655,386.39984 232.6719,379.69343 C 224.06837,386.4525 211.86497,387.55458 200.17582,388.14241 C 185.48949,389.17095 171.14599,389.34237 156.63108,388.14241 C 141.41359,387.94265 123.11048,386.02866 120.23548,380.34335 C 112.63618,372.5254 107.60823,362.99321 104.63736,351.7468 C 102.79692,340.87901 106.09918,331.55401 103.40162,321.20049 C 93.200631,299.54588 81.456827,279.60552 69.541601,258.80803 C 50.51903,224.05512 45.210335,192.2164 47.44427,153.52075 C 62.098848,108.2678 74.182075,84.957039 117.63579,59.932049 C 147.4944,44.673356 171.3532,44.328502 196.92622,47.58354 C 230.59935,52.118115 249.53007,66.252402 264.51805,80.729537 C 288.01853,102.63856 301.06217,128.83317 304.16326,154.17067 C 310.5417,177.42275 307.32043,198.61774 302.2135,219.81274 C 286.39874,251.44225 270.58399,283.07177 254.76923,314.70128 C 249.26279,324.27526 254.72743,353.04865 237.22135,378.39358 C 226.43454,383.7266 209.81934,388.88819 205.37519,383.59296 C 207.32496,378.61023 209.27472,373.62749 211.22449,368.64476 C 189.99372,369.29468 168.76295,369.94461 147.53218,370.59453 C 155.27457,370.23279 155.47432,370.04248 155.33124,365.39515 C 156.1978,349.36375 156.5501,336.93225 157.41666,320.90085 C 161.34251,313.78949 162.35417,310.10661 163.02298,305.90945 C 162.41627,300.09593 155.46689,298.73942 152.46025,287.61177 C 152.36238,280.15756 153.29304,279.38888 160.22354,276.73453 C 164.72777,278.91782 170.94624,279.38687 172.87912,275.05607 C 171.79592,255.34178 170.71271,235.6275 169.62951,215.91321 C 167.46311,200.09845 165.2967,184.2837 163.1303,168.46894 C 172.66248,168.68558 182.19466,168.90222 191.72684,169.11886 C 190.427,203.5647 187.07007,240.92474 185.77023,275.37058 C 189.80541,280.45119 193.8406,277.30346 199.24717,276.55567 C 204.10168,278.26247 205.3563,287.51189 203.35388,290.7615 C 202.80183,297.3417 196.24997,299.4649 194.32653,306.90222 C 206.39973,320.26439 200.98772,347.85472 203.80405,366.70244 M 161.70443,272.07413 C 148.01517,240.84549 134.3259,209.61686 120.63664,178.38822 C 132.07442,172.84968 139.59482,171.3636 151.84309,171.76866 C 154.45213,166.83049 154.49461,164.32378 159.12987,163.57314 C 166.79222,164.85848 169.99687,171.95235 178.87496,171.88687 C 188.87701,171.33578 192.80037,164.43584 199.83061,162.93918 C 205.16655,164.89993 203.47823,169.6974 206.78794,171.2529 C 217.88326,175.83905 227.76285,172.72552 236.29162,178.12216 C 223.73443,209.51513 211.17725,240.90809 198.62006,272.30106',
testLineDrawNative = function() {
    var triangle = paper.path(pathString).attr({
      stroke: '#000000'
    }),
    length = triangle.getTotalLength();
    $('path[fill*="none"]').animate({
      to: 1
    }, {
      duration: 5000,
      step: function(pos, fx) {
          console.log(fx.pos);
        var offset, subpath;
        offset = length*fx.pos;
        subpath = triangle.getSubpath(0, offset);
        paper.clear();
        paper.path(subpath).attr({
          stroke: '#000000'
        });
      }
    });
    console.log($('path[fill*="none"]'));
},
testLineDrawGSAP = function() {
    var triangle = paper.path(pathString).attr({
      stroke: '#000000'
    }),
    obj = {
      length: 0,
      pathLength: triangle.getTotalLength()

    },

    drawLine = function() {

      var offset, subpath;
        offset = obj.pathLength * tween.progress();

        subpath = triangle.getSubpath(0, offset);
        paper.clear();
        paper.path(subpath).attr({
          stroke: '#000000'
        });
    };

    tween = TweenMax.to(triangle, 5, {

        length: obj.pathLength,
        onUpdate: drawLine,
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        onUpdateScope:this

    });
};

$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        paper.clear();
        if($(this).prop('id') === 'native') {
            testLineDrawNative();
        } else {
            testLineDrawGSAP();
        }
    });
});
```